# withSecurityScope not available in NSURL.BookmarkCreationOptions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

im am trying to save a url as a bookmark to persist access to files on an iphone.
To do this i am calling the `bookmarkData` function.
But to prevent errors i have encounterd such as:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist."`

I am trying to add the `withSecurityScope` option when calling the function. 
Although I have found multiple references to this option in the Apple documentation I can't seem to be able to find it when using `NSURL.BookmarkCreationOptions.withSecurityScope`. It only says `'withSecurityScope' is unavailable`. I have also looked through the class definition but still no luck.

I hope someone can help me out here.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There are two phases.

1. You have to create the bookmark data from the url after getting permission (for example in `NSOpenPanel`) and save it

   ```
   let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: [.withSecurityScope])
   UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "mySecureURL")
   ```
2. To use it get the data from `UserDefaults` and resolve it

   ```
   guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "mySecureURL") else { // do some error handling }
   var isStale = false
   let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data, options:[.withSecurityScope], bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale) 
   if isStale { // create new bookmark data from the current url and save it again described in 1. }
   ```

   Now you can use `url` but you have to wrap it in these two lines

   ```
   url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
   // do something with `url`
   url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
   ```

Comment: The problem is that `.withSecurityScope` isn't available at compile time. Xcode highlights `.withSecurityScope` in red and shows the message "'withSecurityScope' is unavailable"

Comment: Your answer was for macOS right? Because .withSecurityScope is not available for iOS.

Comment: @Warpzit Yup, I presume so 
`NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), macCatalyst(13.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios, watchos, tvos) = ( 1 << 11 ), /* include information in the bookmark data which allows the same sandboxed process to access the resource after being relaunched */`