# How to reopen a UIDocument on iCloud using UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, swift, url, uidocumentbrowservc

I've developed a document based iOS app using the `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` (its a game). On startup of the app I want to reopen the last used `UIDocument` automatically. For that I store the url string of the created or opened `UIDocument` in the user defaults and try to open that on `viewDidLoad` of my `DocumentBrowserViewController`. That works fine for documents on local storage but fails on iCloud (or some other foreign) stored documents.

The url string for a locally stored document looks like this:

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F4AF5E0B-C261-47F5-95ED-0B8A1DFEEDE6/Documents/Emsave.emp

The same document on some cloud service has this url string:

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/83CB33FC-5A87-404F-BFB9-8F2910A2192E/File
>   Provider Storage/485172592867551584/Emsave.emp

The viewDidLoad of my DocumentBrowserViewController:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self

        allowsDocumentCreation = true
        allowsPickingMultipleItems = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                                                                // did we already open a game before?
        if let url = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: DocumentBrowserViewController.lastGameKey) {
            print("last opened game: \(url)")
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url) {    // and is the game still existing?
                presentDocument(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))  // open it
            }
        }
    }
```

The test FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url) seems to return always false if the url string specifies a document stored on a cloud service although its there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't hold onto a url you get from the DocumentPicker or the DocumentBrowser, as the file might have moved, been renamed while your app was off.

You should save a bookmark from the url, and recreate the url from the bookmark next time you need it.

Have a look at this section : Bookmarks and Security Scope
in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint but it didn't really solved the problem. I cannot create the bookmark if the URL points to an external storage (like iCloud). On iOS the `BookMarkCreationOption withSecurityScope` is unavailable as stated in this discussion [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524827/withsecurityscope-not-available-in-nsurl-bookmarkcreationoptions] and the entitlement `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope` seems to be not valid on iOS.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the bookmark creation between  [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource] and [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResourde] ?

Comment: Yes, that was missing. Thank you very much; now everything is fine.