# Saving text files to a selected directory, and persisting the chosen directory after the app has closed

Tags: swift, macos, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to give the user the choice to save the files on a directory of his/her choosing. When I pop a `NSOpenPanel()` to let the user select the directory, I can then save a text file there. However, if I save that path and later try to save more files in it without again opening the `NSOpenPanel()`, then I get an error.
Yes, I am aware of the sandboxed nature of the apps, hence my asking the user to select a folder.

How can I save files to the directory chosen by the user, and make sure that going forward the app can continue to save files there.

Here's the code I tried.

With the Open Panel:

```
  func saveNewFile(filename: String) {
        let contents = "Some text..."
        @AppStorage("filesDirectory") var filesDirectory: String = ""
        
        print("saving in: \(filesDirectory)")
        
        do
        {
            let panel = NSOpenPanel()
            panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            panel.canChooseDirectories = true
            panel.canChooseFiles = false
            if panel.runModal() == .OK {
                filesDirectory = panel.url?.path ?? "<none>"
            }
            
            let directoryURL: URL = panel.url!
            
            let documentURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent (filename + ".txt")
            print(documentURL)
            try contents.write (to: documentURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("An error occured: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

And without it

```
func saveNewFile(filename: String) {
    let contents = "Some text..."
    @AppStorage("filesDirectory") var filesDirectory: String = ""
    
    print("saving in: \(filesDirectory)")
    
    do
    {
        /*let panel = NSOpenPanel()
        panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        panel.canChooseDirectories = true
        panel.canChooseFiles = false
        if panel.runModal() == .OK {
            filesDirectory = panel.url?.path ?? "<none>"
        }*/
        
        let directoryURL: URL = URL(string: filesDirectory)!
        
        let documentURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent (filename + ".txt")
        print(documentURL)
        try contents.write (to: documentURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("An error occured: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: Error: An error occured: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=/Users/aleph/test/myfiles/newfile.txt}

Comment: You have to create a *Security Scoped Bookmark* like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524827/withsecurityscope-not-available-in-nsurl-bookmarkcreationoptions/52525158#52525158). And `URL(string` is wrong anyway. You have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath`

Comment: Do not mix URL and String paths, you are saving a file path but when reading it you treat it like a url. Use `URL(fileURLWithPath: filesDirectory)` instead.

Comment: @joakim Thanks, now back the ""You don’t have permission to save the file “ newfile.txt” in the folder “myfiles”." So, how do I save files without having to ask from the user every time to chose a directory?

Comment: @vadian Thank you. Could you provide an example? I'n ew to SwiftUI, and I just tried the code you pointed at and figuring out how to build that Bookmark URL is getting the best of me.

Comment: You repeat writing 'director', not 'directory' in case you needed to know.

Comment: I don't know if your issue is the security-scoped bookmark.  I don't think you need it.  It doesn't look like you are saving filesDirectory correctly in SwiftUI.

Comment: Show the lines of code indicating how you let the user selects a directory.

Comment: @ElTomato thank you. The lines of code are already in the code above. The entire code I use in here. Would you mind pointing to an example of how to do this? I was trying to implement something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124687), but again, I'm just learning swift and I have a bit of trouble understanding what to do. It would be awesome if I could see some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the integration of `@AppStorage`. This is an example of a *Security Scoped Bookmark* with `UserDefaults.standard`

First create a custom error and a convenience method for accessing the security scope reliably.

```
enum ResolveError : Error { case cancelled  }

extension URL {
    func accessSecurityScopedResource<Value>(at url : URL, accessor: (URL) throws -> Value) rethrows -> Value {
        let didStartAccessing = startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        defer { if didStartAccessing { stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }}
        return try accessor(url)
    }
}
```

The method looks quite complicated, but it isn't. The `defer` expression ensures that the security scope is left in a controlled way, and the `throws - rethrows` expression allows to run both non-throwing and throwing code in the closure and you can even return a value from the closure by annotating the type for example

```
let numberOfPages = baseURL.accessSecurityScopedResource(at: fileURL) { url -> Int in
    guard let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) else { return 0 }
    return pdfDocument.pageCount
}
```

---

Then create a method to resolve the bookmark data and show the open dialog in case of missing data

```
func resolveURL(for key: String) throws -> URL {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) {
        var isStale = false
        let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: data, options:[.withSecurityScope], bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
        if isStale {
            let newData = try url.bookmarkData(options: [.withSecurityScope])
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newData, forKey: key)
        }
        return url
    } else {
        let panel = NSOpenPanel()
        panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        panel.canChooseDirectories = true
        panel.canChooseFiles = false
        if panel.runModal() == .OK,
           let url = panel.url {
            let newData = try url.bookmarkData(options: [.withSecurityScope])
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newData, forKey: key)
            return url
        } else {
            throw ResolveError.cancelled
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The behavior of the `isStale` parameter is quite fragile. You might add a finer error handling.

To save some contents into a file in the security scope write

```
let filename = "test"
let contents = "Some Content"
do {
    let directoryURL = try resolveURL(for: "testURL")
    print(directoryURL)
    let documentURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent (filename + ".txt")
    try directoryURL.accessSecurityScopedResource(at: documentURL) { url in
        try contents.write (to: url, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    
} catch let error as ResolveError {
    print("Resolve error:", error)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, now I need to take a second and understand what you did so I can use this for future writes of files as they need to be updated.